# download data error when using ASIHTTPRequest to set the download destination file path in requestDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector: method

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, filenames, content-disposition

i use ASIHTTPRequest to download file to ios device
when i set the download destination file path right after the request has been created, it works well, where my code is:
A

```
SIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/zxllf23/Desktop/download/tmp.zip"]];
    [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:@"/Users/zxllf23/Desktop/download/tmp.zip.download"]];
```

but this is not comfortable, bcs different file on sever have different file name which we can retrive from the http respone header's Content-Disposition, so i want to auto determine file name, and i wrote my code in the requestDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector: method

```
-(void) downloadReceiveRespone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *CoententDecription = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Content-Disposition"];
    NSString *filename = [self getFilenameFrom:CoententDecription];

    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/zxllf23/Desktop/download/%@",filename]];
    [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/zxllf23/Desktop/download/%@.download",filename]];

}
```

where i can download file successfully, but it can not be opened proper, and i compared the downloaded file data with the original file, they are not the same

can any body help me on this issue, i would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Setting setDownloadDestinationPath after the request has started isn't supported, which would explain why it's not working properly.

Either move the file after the request has finished, or write the data to file yourself.

Comment: Thanks JosephH, but in this way, then how can i resume a previous aborted download?

Comment: If you need resuming, I'd go for my first suggestion: moving the file after the request has finished. Then you can just resume as normal, only moving the file to it's final location once it has fully downloaded successfully.

Comment: thanks, but i'm still not quite understand, would you pls explain more detaily, thank you.

Comment: Basically: download the file using a temporary filename, then only after it has finished downloading rename it to the final, proper filename. ie. in the requestDidFinish selector, rename the file to the proper filename.